# PJSIP Hangup call without internet connection

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

I am facing an issue in video calling. The issue is when i make a video call from one device to another device and suddenly my iPhone device lost the internet connection, Then I am unable to Hangup the call. The UI of My iPhone application got stuck. Please let me know the exact way to Hangup call when no internet connection.

Comment: Let the user press the hang up button regardless of the connection state and start the hangup process in the background.

Comment: It blocks the main thread of the application. How would user press the hangup button?

Comment: Did you try to send reinvite() when you lost internet connection?

Comment: Same problem?  it blocks them main thread and i can't do anything